# Owl Carousel hide the overflow but maintain hover state on items

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I've inherited a project which works fine for the most part, but I've swapped the project to full width as opposed to fixed width container, and I'm a bit thrown by the owl carousel. Take a look here: https://shorturl.at/kzHLR and scroll down to the new products/most popular. 4 items fit the width perfectly, and if I take the overflow:visible; off the .carousel-products .owl-wrapper-outer, it hides the other items perfectly.

BUT, it also hides/clips the product hover which I don't want. How can I maintain the product hover but clip the wrapper so it only shows the 4 in view, not the entire width?

Thanks

I've tried to remove the overflow and play with the overflow on the .carousel-products .owl-wrapper-outer, that didn't work. I've also tried forcing the product blocks to be "on top" with z-index, that didn't work either. I've played with some positioning and other overflow settings but I can't get the wrapper to clip and not the box hover.